# rabbitmq server disk space alert

Tags: rabbitmq

I have been receiving alerts regarding the disk space utilization and would like to increase disk space but not sure where the increased usage occurs. The following alert appears:

```
'Rabbit-Disk-Alert' threshold
 Description: Average Disk utilization during the past 15 minutes exceeds 
              75%
```

Now when I log on the server and run

```
df -h
```

It shows the drive that is getting full but I do not know how to find the directory or files that are causing this issue. Is there a way to diagnose this or determine the root of the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `du` command to find the directory taking up space:

```
cd /var
du -hs *
```

More than likely a sub-directory of `/var` is the culprit. The above command will show you which sub-directory (or directories) takes up the most space, and you can change to those directories, re-run `du -hs *`, and continue "downward".

Comment: You may want to check your log files.  The last time I set up RabbitMQ, the default logging was verbose and never cleaned up old entries.  You can set it to roll over however.  Check out [RabbitMQ File and Directory Locations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html).